# Remove the unwanted space in the reopen review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, design

There is some unwanted extra spaces in the right hand side of the Reopen review queue.

Is that space is for any placeholder? If not we can remove those and extend the size of the actual content.

This is an sample [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/13387213), in that if the actual content have more space it will looking good.

Sample screenshot:

[image: Extra space in the Re-open votes reviews]

Comment: The entire site uses a fixed-width view for questions and answers. The review queues use the same width as the actual question page. It has been proposed to redesign the site with a fluid style, but this is rather low on the priority list, I'd imagine.